# Disable FTP protocol in FileZilla

Tags: ftp, redhat-enterprise-linux, filezilla

I'm running RHEL 7 and FileZilla 3.10.1.1.
We have been instructed to remove all insecure protocols from our system.
FileZilla has the ability to SFTP, FTP (unsecure) and FTP over TLS.

Q: How can I prevent FileZilla from using the unsecure FTP protocol?

Comment: It's open source, so you can always create a customized version. From a security standpoint that's a bad decision however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you cannot disable FTP protocol in FileZilla. In general, what's the point of disabling an insecure protocol in a *client* application? Disable it on your *servers*. If you do not want your users to access an *external* server using a plain FTP, block it on the *firewall* (your network firewall or local desktop firewall).

Btw, you are using six years old version of FileZilla. You might have other more serious problems to deal with.

Comment: I agree with you. It does seem a bit pointless, but: There is an external server that still has FTP services enabled. Our software, which uses FileZilla, connects with FTP to retrieve files. Our Blue Team identified the ports going active on _our_ network. We now have a POA&M to remove it.

Comment: Can't say why it's a 6 year old version of FileZilla, but I can say, it's not supposed to work on the Enterprise version of Red Hat. I have no idea why we are using it. That windmill is being charged by someone else and not under my purview.

Comment: 1-Firewall is not under my control; 2-It will (eventually) go away. I want to prevent it now so we can find any problems before it is too late; 3-If the user tries to connect with FTP, the port will become active -- which I also need to prevent.

Comment: We are inside an enclave. We do not use firewalls on client machines. Enabling them wreaks havoc with our software -- too many machines with unique configurations. Maintaining them would be a logistical nightmare. That's why we went with an enclave.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have control over user management? I'm not very familiar with RHEL but one hacky solution: you could force users to connect with a username and SSH keypair.

If you do not share a username/password combination but instead provide clients with a username and the SSH private key to import into their FileZilla site manager, this would force an SFTP connection. The [FileZilla wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto) has more notes on importing and creating keys.

This answer based on a couple assumptions:

- You are in control of user creation (or at least circulating credentials)
- You have a small group of users and/or an automated way to manage and circulate private keys for all users

Comment: As OP commented, this is about an external server. Anyway, if it was about a server under OP's control, there's no need to switch to keys. OP could just turn off FTP, right?

Comment: Yes. I want to turn off FTP. Any traffic on ports 20/21 is "bad" and needs to be prevented.

Comment: Thanks for the Filezilla wiki page suggestion!